# tsql do update queries that join other tables lock the joined tables also?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, update, azure-sql-managed-instance

Azure SQL Managed Instance. If I am updating a temp table, and joining to another table or tables, do the joined tables also get locked, even though the update statement is only updating the temp table? I'm trying to figure out why this query would cause blocking.

```
UPDATE M SET M.MatchWgt = M.MatchWgt + 80
FROM #MatchPossibles M JOIN LostHD L ON M.PossibleMatchID = L.ID
JOIN LostHD L1 ON L1.PhoneNumber = L.PhoneNumber AND L1.ID = M.IDtoMatch;
```

Should I be using the `NOLOCK` hint on the "read only" tables?

Comment: How do you know this query is causing blocking?

Comment: @DaleK it is part of a series of similar queries in a stored procedure. The sp is causing blocking, which I have determined using a variety of tools including sp_who2.

Comment: Have you determined which tables are causing blocking?

Comment: Any table being accessed will have locked placed on it to ensure the ACID properties of the database. But if the table is only being read, then only shared locks should be placed which won't prevent reading elsewhere. The simple answer to "Should I be using the NOLOCK hint on the "read only" tables?" is usually NO, but ultimately its your decision - you just need to be very aware of the consequences of doing so.

Comment: @DaleK `#MatchPossibles` is a temp table which only exists in the context of the sp, therefore it must be the other table that is blocking. The other table is a busy one; it could be being updated at any given time, though it is unlikely the rows in question would be updated at the same time the sp is being run. The sp is also quite busy, but these aren't mission critical transactions, so I don't care if the underlying data changes while the sp is executing. Basically, all I need is a snapshot of the data for purposes of this sp.

Comment: sp_who and sp_who2 are quite unreliable. You're better off using [sp_WhoIsActive](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive/blob/master/who_is_active.sql) to troubleshoot blocking scenarios. There's quite a bit of [useful documentation](http://whoisactive.com/docs/) about how to use it.

Comment: @ErikDarling I will look at the documentation for sp_WhoIsActive.

Comment: In addition to Erik's excellent advice, if you are able to capture an example of the blocking occurring with the `sp_WhoIsActive` procedure and want to update your post with the results, then we may be able to better help you understand what's going on.